# React-Bootstrap with Webpack not working from react-starter-kit

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, webpack, webpack-2, react-bootstrap

Please I need some help as I'm having a hard time trying to use bootstrap and react-bootstrap in my new project created from a react-starter-kit template (https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit).

I'm pretty new to webpack so I'm not pretty sure what I need to do to get this working.

The steps I did so far:

1) I included react-bootstrap, bootstrap and jquery in package.json
2) I imported a react-bootstrap button in home file and tried to rendered. It renders with no style at all.

What else needs to be done?

This is the webpack.config:

```
/**
 * React Starter Kit (https://www.reactstarterkit.com/)
 *
 * Copyright © 2014-present Kriasoft, LLC. All rights reserved.
 *
 * This source code is licensed under the MIT license found in the
 * LICENSE.txt file in the root directory of this source tree.
 */

import path from 'path';
import webpack from 'webpack';
import AssetsPlugin from 'assets-webpack-plugin';
import { BundleAnalyzerPlugin } from 'webpack-bundle-analyzer';
import pkg from '../package.json';

const isDebug = !process.argv.includes('--release');
const isVerbose = process.argv.includes('--verbose');
const isAnalyze = process.argv.includes('--analyze') || process.argv.includes('--analyse');

//
// Common configuration chunk to be used for both
// client-side (client.js) and server-side (server.js) bundles
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

const config = {
  context: path.resolve(__dirname, '..'),

  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../build/public/assets'),
    publicPath: '/assets/',
    pathinfo: isVerbose,
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        include: [
          path.resolve(__dirname, '../src'),
        ],
        query: {
          // https://github.com/babel/babel-loader#options
          cacheDirectory: isDebug,

          // https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/options/
          babelrc: false,
          presets: [
            // A Babel preset that can automatically determine the Babel plugins and polyfills
            // https://github.com/babel/babel-preset-env
            ['env', {
              targets: {
                browsers: pkg.browserslist,
              },
              modules: false,
              useBuiltIns: false,
              debug: false,
            }],
            // Experimental ECMAScript proposals
            // https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/#presets-stage-x-experimental-presets-
            'stage-2',
            // JSX, Flow
            // https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/master/packages/babel-preset-react
            'react',
            // Optimize React code for the production build
            // https://github.com/thejameskyle/babel-react-optimize
            ...isDebug ? [] : ['react-optimize'],
          ],
          plugins: [
            // Adds component stack to warning messages
            // https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/master/packages/babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx-source
            ...isDebug ? ['transform-react-jsx-source'] : [],
            // Adds __self attribute to JSX which React will use for some warnings
            // https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/master/packages/babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx-self
            ...isDebug ? ['transform-react-jsx-self'] : [],
          ],
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.css/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'isomorphic-style-loader',
          },
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              // CSS Loader https://github.com/webpack/css-loader
              importLoaders: 1,
              sourceMap: isDebug,
              // CSS Modules https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules
              modules: true,
              localIdentName: isDebug ? '[name]-[local]-[hash:base64:5]' : '[hash:base64:5]',
              // CSS Nano http://cssnano.co/options/
              minimize: !isDebug,
              discardComments: { removeAll: true },
            },
          },
          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
              config: './tools/postcss.config.js',
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.md$/,
        loader: path.resolve(__dirname, './lib/markdown-loader.js'),
      },
      {
        test: /\.txt$/,
        loader: 'raw-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        query: {
          name: isDebug ? '[path][name].[ext]?[hash:8]' : '[hash:8].[ext]',
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        query: {
          name: isDebug ? '[path][name].[ext]?[hash:8]' : '[hash:8].[ext]',
          limit: 10000,
        },
      },
    ],
  },

  // Don't attempt to continue if there are any errors.
  bail: !isDebug,

  cache: isDebug,

  stats: {
    colors: true,
    reasons: isDebug,
    hash: isVerbose,
    version: isVerbose,
    timings: true,
    chunks: isVerbose,
    chunkModules: isVerbose,
    cached: isVerbose,
    cachedAssets: isVerbose,
  },
};

//
// Configuration for the client-side bundle (client.js)
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

const clientConfig = {
  ...config,

  name: 'client',
  target: 'web',

  entry: {
    client: ['babel-polyfill', './src/client.js'],
  },

  output: {
    ...config.output,
    filename: isDebug ? '[name].js' : '[name].[chunkhash:8].js',
    chunkFilename: isDebug ? '[name].chunk.js' : '[name].[chunkhash:8].chunk.js',
  },

  plugins: [
    // Define free variables
    // https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#defineplugin
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': isDebug ? '"development"' : '"production"',
      'process.env.BROWSER': true,
      __DEV__: isDebug,
    }),

    // Emit a file with assets paths
    // https://github.com/sporto/assets-webpack-plugin#options
    new AssetsPlugin({
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../build'),
      filename: 'assets.json',
      prettyPrint: true,
    }),

    // Move modules that occur in multiple entry chunks to a new entry chunk (the commons chunk).
    // http://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#commonschunkplugin
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'vendor',
      minChunks: module => /node_modules/.test(module.resource),
    }),

    ...isDebug ? [] : [
      // Minimize all JavaScript output of chunks
      // https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2#compressor-options
      new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
        sourceMap: true,
        compress: {
          screw_ie8: true, // React doesn't support IE8
          warnings: isVerbose,
          unused: true,
          dead_code: true,
        },
        mangle: {
          screw_ie8: true,
        },
        output: {
          comments: false,
          screw_ie8: true,
        },
      }),
    ],

    // Webpack Bundle Analyzer
    // https://github.com/th0r/webpack-bundle-analyzer
    ...isAnalyze ? [new BundleAnalyzerPlugin()] : [],
  ],

  // Choose a developer tool to enhance debugging
  // http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#devtool
  devtool: isDebug ? 'cheap-module-source-map' : false,

  // Some libraries import Node modules but don't use them in the browser.
  // Tell Webpack to provide empty mocks for them so importing them works.
  // https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#node
  // https://github.com/webpack/node-libs-browser/tree/master/mock
  node: {
    fs: 'empty',
    net: 'empty',
    tls: 'empty',
  },
};

//
// Configuration for the server-side bundle (server.js)
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

const serverConfig = {
  ...config,

  name: 'server',
  target: 'node',

  entry: {
    server: ['babel-polyfill', './src/server.js'],
  },

  output: {
    ...config.output,
    filename: '../../server.js',
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs2',
  },

  module: {
    ...config.module,

    // Override babel-preset-env configuration for Node.js
    rules: config.module.rules.map(rule => (rule.loader !== 'babel-loader' ? rule : {
      ...rule,
      query: {
        ...rule.query,
        presets: rule.query.presets.map(preset => (preset[0] !== 'env' ? preset : ['env', {
          targets: {
            node: parseFloat(pkg.engines.node.replace(/^\D+/g, '')),
          },
          modules: false,
          useBuiltIns: false,
          debug: false,
        }])),
      },
    })),
  },

  externals: [
    /^\.\/assets\.json$/,
    (context, request, callback) => {
      const isExternal =
        request.match(/^[@a-z][a-z/.\-0-9]*$/i) &&
        !request.match(/\.(css|less|scss|sss)$/i);
      callback(null, Boolean(isExternal));
    },
  ],

  plugins: [
    // Define free variables
    // https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#defineplugin
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': isDebug ? '"development"' : '"production"',
      'process.env.BROWSER': false,
      __DEV__: isDebug,
    }),

    // Do not create separate chunks of the server bundle
    // https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#limitchunkcountplugin
    new webpack.optimize.LimitChunkCountPlugin({ maxChunks: 1 }),

    // Adds a banner to the top of each generated chunk
    // https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#bannerplugin
    new webpack.BannerPlugin({
      banner: 'require("source-map-support").install();',
      raw: true,
      entryOnly: false,
    }),
  ],

  node: {
    console: false,
    global: false,
    process: false,
    Buffer: false,
    __filename: false,
    __dirname: false,
  },

  devtool: isDebug ? 'cheap-module-source-map' : 'source-map',
};

export default [clientConfig, serverConfig];
```

Then the package.json:

```
{
  "name": "web",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=6.5",
    "npm": ">=3.10"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">1%",
    "last 4 versions",
    "Firefox ESR",
    "not ie < 9"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.23.0",
    "bluebird": "^3.5.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.17.1",
    "classnames": "^2.2.5",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "express": "^4.15.2",
    "express-graphql": "^0.6.4",
    "express-jwt": "^5.3.0",
    "fastclick": "^1.0.6",
    "graphql": "^0.9.3",
    "history": "^4.6.1",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "isomorphic-style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^7.3.0",
    "normalize.css": "^6.0.0",
    "passport": "^0.3.2",
    "passport-facebook": "^2.1.1",
    "pretty-error": "^2.1.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.5.8",
    "query-string": "^4.3.4",
    "react": "^15.5.4",
    "react-dom": "^15.5.4",
    "serialize-javascript": "^1.3.0",
    "source-map-support": "^0.4.14",
    "universal-router": "^3.1.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.30.0",
    "jquery": "^2.2.1",
    "bootstrap-webpack": "0.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "assets-webpack-plugin": "^3.5.1",
    "autoprefixer": "^6.7.7",
    "babel-cli": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-core": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-eslint": "^7.2.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-rewire": "^1.1.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.4.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react-optimize": "^1.0.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-register": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-template": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-types": "^6.24.1",
    "browser-sync": "^2.18.8",
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "chokidar": "^1.6.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.0",
    "editorconfig-tools": "^0.1.1",
    "enzyme": "^2.8.2",
    "eslint": "^3.19.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^14.1.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^1.7.1",
    "eslint-plugin-css-modules": "^2.7.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^6.10.3",
    "file-loader": "^0.11.1",
    "front-matter": "^2.1.2",
    "glob": "^7.1.1",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "lint-staged": "^3.4.0",
    "markdown-it": "^8.3.1",
    "mkdirp": "^0.5.1",
    "mocha": "^3.3.0",
    "pixrem": "^3.0.2",
    "pleeease-filters": "^3.0.1",
    "postcss": "^5.2.17",
    "postcss-calc": "^5.3.1",
    "postcss-color-function": "^3.0.0",
    "postcss-custom-media": "^5.0.1",
    "postcss-custom-properties": "^5.0.2",
    "postcss-custom-selectors": "^3.0.0",
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "^2.1.1",
    "postcss-global-import": "^1.0.0",
    "postcss-import": "^9.1.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^1.3.3",
    "postcss-media-minmax": "^2.1.2",
    "postcss-nested": "^1.0.1",
    "postcss-nesting": "^2.3.1",
    "postcss-pseudoelements": "^4.0.0",
    "postcss-selector-matches": "^2.0.5",
    "postcss-selector-not": "^2.0.0",
    "pre-commit": "^1.2.2",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.5.1",
    "react-deep-force-update": "^2.0.1",
    "react-hot-loader": "^3.0.0-beta.6",
    "redbox-react": "^1.3.6",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.1",
    "sinon": "^2.1.0",
    "stylefmt": "^5.3.2",
    "stylelint": "^7.10.1",
    "stylelint-config-standard": "^16.0.0",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.8",
    "webpack": "^2.4.1",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.4.0",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.10.2",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.18.0",
    "write-file-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.2"
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      [
        "env",
        {
          "targets": {
            "node": "current"
          }
        }
      ],
      "stage-2",
      "react"
    ],
    "env": {
      "test": {
        "plugins": [
          "rewire"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "stylelint": {
    "extends": "stylelint-config-standard",
    "rules": {
      "string-quotes": "single",
      "property-no-unknown": [
        true,
        {
          "ignoreProperties": [
            "composes"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "selector-pseudo-class-no-unknown": [
        true,
        {
          "ignorePseudoClasses": [
            "global"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.{cmd,html,json,md,sh,txt,xml,yml}": [
      "editorconfig-tools fix",
      "git add"
    ],
    "*.{js,jsx}": [
      "eslint --fix",
      "git add"
    ],
    "*.{css,less,scss,sss}": [
      "stylefmt",
      "stylelint",
      "git add"
    ]
  },
  "scripts": {
    "lint:fix": "eslint --fix src tools",
    "lint:js": "eslint src tools",
    "lint:css": "stylelint \"src/**/*.{css,less,scss,sss}\"",
    "lint:staged": "lint-staged",
    "lint": "yarn run lint:js && yarn run lint:css",
    "test": "mocha \"src/**/*.test.js\" --require babel-register --require test/setup.js",
    "test:watch": "yarn run test -- --reporter min --watch",
    "clean": "babel-node tools/run clean",
    "copy": "babel-node tools/run copy",
    "bundle": "babel-node tools/run bundle",
    "build": "babel-node tools/run build",
    "build:stats": "yarn run build -- --release --analyse",
    "deploy": "babel-node tools/run deploy",
    "render": "babel-node tools/run render",
    "serve": "babel-node tools/run runServer",
    "start:brk": "babel-node --debug-brk tools/run start",
    "start:dev": "babel-node tools/run start",
    "start": "node build/server.js"
  }
}
```

And finally my Home.js

```
/**
 * React Starter Kit (https://www.reactstarterkit.com/)
 *
 * Copyright © 2014-present Kriasoft, LLC. All rights reserved.
 *
 * This source code is licensed under the MIT license found in the
 * LICENSE.txt file in the root directory of this source tree.
 */

import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import withStyles from 'isomorphic-style-loader/lib/withStyles';
import s from './Home.css';
import {Button} from 'react-bootstrap';

class Home extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    news: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
      title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      link: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      content: PropTypes.string,
    })).isRequired,
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className={s.root}>
        <div className={s.container}>
          <h1>React.js News</h1>
          <Button bsStyle="primary">Primary</Button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withStyles(s)(Home);
```

Comment: Does it work now? Thanks.

Comment: Hello Jonathan, thank you, unhopefully it does not work, I just added the css into my index.html, maybe the problem is that this starter uses isomorphic style loader instead of normal style loader, and I'll have to change something in my webpack config

Comment: Did you add the CDN links into the head tag, not webpack?

Comment: Sure. Make a test, download the starter from : https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit and add the CDN links to the index.html. Not working

Comment: Thanks I will take a look

Comment: I installed the starter kit and everything is working as expected. I updated my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the bootstrap CSS manually:

> Because React-Bootstrap doesn't depend on a very precise version of Bootstrap, we don't ship with any included css.

[More info here](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction#stylesheets)

Add the bootstrap stylesheet inside `src/components/Html.js`

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
```

Usage (e.g: Home.js)

```
<Button bsStyle="primary">Default</Button>
<h1>React.js News</h1>
<Alert bsStyle="warning"> Hello </Alert>
```

Please take a look there:

https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit/pull/782

https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit/issues/950

Comment: Probably I added the cdns in the wrong file. THANK YOU SO MUCH!